# My relationships are missing in strapi model afterCreate

Tags: strapi

I have created a model with a relationship to another model.

I want to send an email with the entry information, afterCreate seems like the place to do so. But it doesn't contain my relationship fields on the `model` object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Strapi 3.0.0, the model lifecycles have changed and now `afterCreate` does contain relationships.

Answer (score 0):

We have an issue about that on GitHub, there is currently not workaround about that.

Alex is re-writing the logic behind the life cycle function, so lot of issue should be fixed on that after the release of the new system.